# Can someone tell me what a world with a radius 1.2 times that of earth’s would be like?

Tags: planets, physics, earth-like

I want to make a world larger than earth for a story I want to write. Please can someone tell me about the different characteristics a world with a 20% larger radius would have:

- How much gravity it would have
- How many hours the days would be if it rotated at the same speed as earth on the surface
- How much surface area it would have
- How much land ( with the same land to sea ratio as earth )
- and other info about the physics of the planet what effects the larger radius would have.

Also, the atmospheric pressure, and the speed of the atmospheric winds would be the same as Earth, as well as the density of the planet.

Comment: Hi, Rohan. This sounds like it is either (a) a math problem, and a simple one at that, or (b) something you could write an entire story about. Distances would be 1.2 times ours, areas would be 1.44 times, , and volumes would be 1.7 times. All of this is readily accessible with a little googling.

Comment: I did try googling before coming here, however I couldn’t find any answers, just equations on how to work out the gravity of earth. I might not have been typing the questions well, but I definitely searched quite hard for a while before coming here and was unable to find anything specific to this. Thank you for commenting though.

Comment: Hi Rohan! I think a lot of your subquestions will depend on the composition of the world in question. L Dutch closed the question for lack of details & clarity. This means that, in addition to your question, you should also provide information about the planet, in particular, what is its composition. That would help with density and gravity. As for your questions of surface area, Earth hours per day, land/sea ratios and the like, those are basic maths questions. We don't answer those here. Hint: you can find surface area calculators on google.

Comment: On top of what @elemtilas, you should also narrow down your question to be specific. "tell me something about this planet" is as open ended as it can get

Comment: Can anyone tell me what a world with a radius of 1.04 times that of Earth's would be like?

Comment: I think this is answerable with your added details. You'll get dinged for "asking multiple questions" but I would argue that it's really one question, and we don't actually want 5 different questions posted about individual details of the same planet. The answer to gravity is interesting, actually, but it's naughty to post answers as comments so I won't tell you. ;)

Comment: For future reference, please understand that asking multiple questions is literally a specific reason to close questions.

Comment: Most of this is still really basic math (surface area of a sphere, etc.) the _gravity_ question is indeed interesting.